# Determining search radius for proximity search in ArcGIS API for Java?

Tags: esri-geometry-api-java

I am using Java's Esri-geometry-api, to find out given a point A the 50s nearest points within a radius of distance from the point A:

```
MultiPoint g = new MultiPoint()
GeometryEngine.getNearestVertices(g, new Point(0.283437724779, 52.9060144241), searchRadius, 50)
```

where the `Point` is in WGS84 coordinates. How do I calculate the `searchRadius` for a given distance from that point (for example 1 Miles or 1.6 Km)???

Comment: [Cross-reference GitHub issue](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/issues/107)

Answer (score 1):

According to this sample, the units of the searchRadius input parameter is in "map units".
Note the very last line of Esri's code sample here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/nearest-vertices/

```
 // maximum search radius panel
JPanel panelRadius = new JPanel();
panelRadius.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelRadius, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
panelRadius.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,10,5,5));
panelRadius.add(new JLabel("Search radius: "));
txtRadius = new JTextField("20", 10);
txtRadius.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
txtRadius.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
panelRadius.add(txtRadius);
panelRadius.add(new JLabel(" map units"));
```

Comment: I have already checked that example but I don't get the sense of it: `int maxRadius = Integer.parseInt(txtRadius.getText().trim());`